# pmd:GuardLogStatementJavaUtil broken?

Tags: java, pmd

Setup:

- SonarQube PMD Plugin 2.6 (= PMD version? 5.5.0? Not listed: https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pmd)

> Guard Log Statement Java Util (pmd:GuardLogStatementJavaUtil)
>
> Whenever using a log level, one should check if the loglevel is actually enabled, or otherwise skip the associate String creation and manipulation.
>
> Example:
>
> // Add this for performance
>
> if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) { ...
>   log.fine("This happens");

Code (which triggers violation):

```
LOGGER.info(() -> "Bla bla");
```

Implementation of lambda:

```
@Override
public void info(Supplier<String> message) {
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info(message.get());
    }
}
```

**Is the rule broken? If so, is this a known issue?**

Comment: What is your question and why it is on SO instead of PMD and/or Sonarqube bug trackers?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin There is no public issue tracker for SonarQube and I'm not sure about the PMD version that is used. Also, I'm not sure about the relationship between the two tools and would like to get a confirmation that this is a bug

Answer (score 0):

The discussion has been moved to the PMD issue tracker: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/370